# How to get the drop box empty at the start in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I use drop box to display three options,

```
selectInput("select", label = h5("Choose Annotation DB"),
                                          choices = list("h10kcod.db"="h10kcod","h20kcod.db"="h20kcod","hwgcod.db"="hwgcod")),
                                       selected = NULL)
```

But it always have the first choice in the drop box already selected, however i am interested to get the drop box empty(with no one selected). How should i do that. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello look at this example :

```
library("shiny")

ui = fluidPage(
  # method 1 : put an empty element "" in your list
  selectInput("select", label = h5("Choose Annotation DB"),
              choices = list("",     "h10kcod.db"="h10kcod","h20kcod.db"="h20kcod","hwgcod.db"="hwgcod")),
  # method 2 : use selectizeInput and the placeholder option
  selectizeInput("select", label = h5("Choose Annotation DB"),
          choices = list("h10kcod.db"="h10kcod","h20kcod.db"="h20kcod","hwgcod.db"="hwgcod"),
          options = list(placeholder = 'A placeholder',
                         onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')))
)

server = function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: **method 1** is a very elegant solution and works perfect.